# Juniper Software upgrade faills cause of not enough space

Tags: ansible

I've tried to update a EX2300 switch from Juniper with the ansible module(juniper_junos_software) but eveytime i tried it fails cause it doesn't have enough space and i tried a bunch of stuff all from trying to SCP with other Ansible modules such as (net_put and junipernetworks.junos.junos_scp) which to no relief i can't get to work either

The Ansible code is:

```
- name: Install Junos OS
  hosts: EX
  roles:
   - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
   OS_version: "20.4R1.12"
   OS_package: "junos-arm-32-20.4R1.12.tgz"
   pkg_dir: "/etc/JunOS"
   log_dir: "/var/log"
   netconf_port: 830
   wait_time: 3600

  tasks:
    - name: Checking NETCONF connectivity
      wait_for:
       host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
       port: "{{ netconf_port }}"
       timeout: 5

    - name: Clean up the device
      juniper_junos_command:
       commands: 
         - request system snapshot delete snap*
         - request system software delete jweb
       timeout: 200
      register: response

    - name: Print response from Clean up the device
      debug:
        var: response

    - name: Install Junos OS package
      juniper_junos_software:
       version: "{{ OS_version }}"
       local_package: "{{ pkg_dir }}/{{ OS_package }}"
       cleanfs: yes
       validate: no
       reboot: true
       logfile: "{{ log_dir }}/ansible.log"
      register: sw
      notify:
       - wait_reboot

    - name: Print response
      debug:
        var: response

    - name: Snapshot Slice alternate
      juniper_junos_command:
       commands: request system snapshot slice alternate
       timeout: 200
      register: response

  handlers:
   - name: wait_reboot
     wait_for:
       host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
       port: "{{ netconf_port }}"
       timeout: "{{ wait_time }}"
     when: not sw.check_mode
```

The error i get is:

```
   "changed": true,
    "check_mode": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attempts": null,
            "baud": null,
            "checksum": null,
            "checksum_algorithm": "md5",
            "checksum_timeout": 300,
            "cleanfs_timeout": 300,
            "console": null,
            "cs_passwd": null,
            "cs_user": null,
            "force_host": false,
            "host": "10.15.84.100",
            "issu": false,
            "level": null,
            "logdir": null,
            "logfile": "/var/log/ansible.log",
            "mode": null,
            "nssu": false,
            "passwd": null,
            "port": 830,
            "provider": null,
            "ssh_config": null,
            "ssh_private_key_file": "/etc/ansible/ssh-keys/id_ed25519",
            "timeout": 30,
            "user": "ansible",
            "validate": false,
            "vmhost": false
        }
    },
    "msg": [
        "Unable to install the software %s",
        "\nERROR: estimate of space required: 119 Mbytes, available: 41 Mbytes\n"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"space required: 119 Mbytes, available: 41 Mbytes" indicates you need to delete some files, usually image files.